Should the Bitcoin tag be permitted if another useful tag is included?
I tried to tag a question with "bitcoin" and was unable to, even though I had other qualifying tags.
Given that not every post on this site refers to Bitcoin-per se, I think that the tag may resolve some confusion when dealing with shared terms such as "transaction"
Question
Should the Bitcoin tag be conditionally allowed if there is another qualifying tag (Bitcoin can't be the only tag)

In my opinion, unless you have a tag like 'ripple,' you're dealing with bitcoin by default.

I agree with Nick's comment. This site is mainly about Bitcoin, the site name is "Bitcoin" and the overwhelming majority of questions is about Bitcoin. Users should assume that the question is about Bitcoin unless it is tagged with another crypto-currency.
If things change in the future and other crypto-currencies start to really compete with Bitcoin we might have to reconsider.
